# Solving an integration-solution contains the integrating variable

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have below function to integrate;$$\int_{-1}^{1} A(\cos(\theta)) d(\cos(\theta)),$$ where $$A(\cos(\theta))=\int_{0}^{\cos(\theta)}J_{0}(t) dt,$$ $J_{0}$ is Bessel function of zero order.

Below shows my attempt to solve the expression,
$$\int_{-1}^{1} A(\cos(\theta)) d(\cos(\theta))= \int_{0}^{\cos(\theta)}\int_{-1}^{1}J_{0}(t) \ d(\cos(\theta))\ dt$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1} A(\cos(\theta)) d(\cos(\theta))= \int_{0}^{\cos(\theta)}J_{0}(t) [\cos(\theta)]_{-1}^{1}dt=2\int_{0}^{\cos(\theta)}J_{0}(t) \ dt$$
Therefore,
$$\int_{-1}^{1} A(\cos(\theta)) d(\cos(\theta))= 2A(\cos(\theta))$$

I dont see any mistake in this calculation. However, how comes still I am ending up with a function with $\cos(\theta)$ term?

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the step

$$
\int_{-1}^{1} A(\cos(\theta)) \mathrm d(\cos(\theta))= \int_{0}^{\cos(\theta)}\int_{-1}^{1}J_{0}(t) \ \mathrm d(\cos(\theta))\ \mathrm dt
$$

you switched the integrations even though the upper limit of the inner one contained the integration variable of the outer one. The correct result would have been

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{\cos(\theta)}J_{0}(t) \ \mathrm dt\ \mathrm d(\cos(\theta))\;.
$$

This integral vanishes, since $J_0$ is even so that

$$
\int_0^{-\cos(\theta)}J_0(t)\ \mathrm dt=-\int_0^{\cos(\theta)}J_0(t)\ \mathrm dt\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Now I  understand :)